# Class design for actions with certain parameters

Tags: c#

I'm currently working on a WPF C# system where there a number of 'Process' modes, such as `Guillotine` or `Turretting`. For each of these modes, an `action` can be performed against each `job` currently at that mode - this can be `Start`, `Stop`, `Pause`, `Resume` and `Complete`.

Currently I have a base class for the 'JobAction', and classes for `Start`, `Stop` etc which extend that. Inside the base class I have an if statement to check the current process.

This seems like it could be vastly improved, but I don't know how to design it. Any ideas?

Comment: So the question is: how to apply the same actions for different processes... I understand?

Comment: Yes, sorry if the question is a little unclear on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the process `if` with the decorator pattern.

You'll decorate `JobAction` with a `GuillotineProcessDecorator` or `TurrettingProcessDecorator`. You could decide which decorator to use at the composition root using an IoC container such as `SimpleInjector`.

The decorator pattern allows you to add functionality to an object without the rigidity of typical class hierarchies. So you can easily add further Processes in the future and combine processes.

**The decorator pattern:**

> Attach additional responsibilities to an object dynamically.
>   Decorators provide a flexible alternative to subclassing for extending
>   functionality.

An implementation would look something like:

```
public abstract class JobActionBase
{
    public abstract void Start() {}
    public abstract void Stop() {}
    public abstract void Pause() {}
    public abstract void Resume() {}
    public abstract void Complete() {}
}

public class JobAction : JobActionBase
{
    public void Start() {}
    public void Stop() {}
    public void Pause() {}
    public void Resume() {}
    public void Complete() {}
}

public abstract class Decorator : JobActionBase
{
    protected JobActionBase jobAction;

    public void Decorate(JobActionBase jobAction)
    {
        this.jobAction = jobAction;
    }

    public override void Start()
    {
       if (jobAction != null)
       {
           jobAction.Start();
       }
    }
}

public class GuillotineProcessDecorator : Decorator
{
    public override void Start()
    {
        base.Operation();
        // Do something that's Guillotine specific
    }
 }

// Encapsulate this in a factory
JobAction jobAction = new JobAction();
GuillotineProcessDecorator d = new GuillotineProcessDecorator();
d.Decorate(jobAction);
d.Sale();
```

Comment: Are there any resources that'll help implement a decorator pattern in the way I require?

Comment: I have provided an example implementation. http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternDecorator.aspx